# How to make a powershell script execute on every user login automatically?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am trying to make it so a script I dumped in c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\startup executes with elevated privileges.  What the script does is clears out all users downloads\documents\desktop folders in a for loop, so it'll go user by user and delete data out of those folders.  I cannot get it run successfully so far as the average user on the domain doesn't have privileges to delete other's data.  How can I do this?

We use Windows 7 on all our workstations.  I am not a system administrator by the way, I know there are better ways to do what I am trying to do, but I am trying to make these 40 work stations run better because we don't have any policies restricting how much the user can save onto the local drives etc.  And the team that does manage this doesn't want to be bothered by a help desk technician.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a startup script in that manner or at least shouldn't if you do manage to do it, it's likely that those credentials will be stored in a manner that it's readable for every user.

Consider setting up a planned task instead. You could give that task elevated permissions in a secure manner and let it run on user login.

Be careful of straight up deleting that data and inform the users of those workstations. There might be sensitive/important work stored in those locations.

Comment: These are workstations that have different users on them every day, to be fair, they are not supposed to be storing anything important on there and are supposed to be using their mapped network drive.  I did inform the Manager of the area and we gave the users 2 weeks to move any important data to their respective drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could do this using the Windows Task Scheduler, but you may not have permissions to set that up if you aren't a domain administrator. Or your admins may have disabled it somehow or have some process that prevents you from saving your changes. Even if you do get it to work it's probably going to (rightly) irritate the help desk guys.

I would strongly recommend going through the official channel unless the company policy is that you guys are self supported. If it works, it may be temporary and they push out a standardized config that wipes your changes. Or it might waste a lot of their time trying to diagnose some seemingly unrelated issue because they don't know about it. They might even be fine with you just explaining what you're going to do and getting them to 'sign off' on it, so at least they're aware of that config.

Task Scheduler can be found in Computer Management (right click 'My Computer' in explorer, select 'Manage'). It allows you to set a task to be run under whatever credentials you choose and has a ton of triggering options, one of which is 'at log on' and you can choose specific users that need the script executed or 'any user'.

Comment: Going through the official channels here is a drag, and honestly the last time I did that, they told me to just jerry rig a solution instead of them creating a new OU for a specific subset of machines we were having a problem with.  So I'm just going to take matters into my own hands :).  Task scheduler sounds like a good idea, and it seems it is not blocked by a group policy on our machines.. beautiful.  Thank you!